# Cannot access my router webpage because Chrome forces https

Tags: google-chrome, http, https, microsoft-edge

I cannot access my router webpage which is http://192.168.1.1 because it gets redirected to https://192.168.1.1 (gives me `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`). I know that google switched to https for some reasons, but I cannot open the router at all.

Failed Solutions:

1. Tried Using Chrome & Edge on Laptop but failed to open the webpage.
2. Tried to open the webpage using chrome on my phone but failed to open the webpage
3. Tried to open `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and query for `192.168.1.1` but it gives me `Not Found`; It appears that it does not work with ip as well as websites.
4. Tried to open anonymous webpage but failed to open the webpage.

This issue is very recent and any solutions on stackoverflow did not help.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try Windows Chromium Edge. That works for my two routers, tells me "unsafe" and I then open the router page successfully.

Comment: [Yes HSTS does not apply to addresses](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6797#section-8.1.1). If Win10+ try `curl -i http://192.168.1.1` to see if the _router_ is redirecting; if so, nothing you do browser-side can help. I've never had any trouble doing non-s with Chrome (including current 98.0.4758.82) on Win8.1 and Win10.

Comment: how old is your router? a cipher mismatch implies that one of the devices is much much newer than the other.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you for the help, yes the router has no issues, i downloaded opera and it works just fine because it does not simply redirect to https

Comment: Use a browser that isn't Chrome.

Comment: Do start/run h ttp://192.168.1.1 and press enter, and if this don't work update router firmware or replace.

Answer (score 0):

One way to address this is via reverse proxying.

- Put a web server on your network, such as Apache; maybe already you have one.
- Create a host name for the router,e.g `router.local`, which is actually just an alias for the web server, and not 192.168.1.1.
- In the web server, create a virtual host definition for `router.local` which reverse proxies to 192.168.1.1.

Here is an Apache definition I'm actually using for this. It requires some modules to be loaded like `mod_proxy` and `mod_https` and of course `mod_ssl`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName router.local
  ServerAlias router    
  SSLEngine on
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/router.log common
  ProxyPass "/" "http://192.168.1.1/"
  ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://192.168.1.1/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Why you likely need a virtual host rather than, say, just proxying a sub-page URL like `webserver.local/router` is that the router's web UI likely contains absolute references to resources like `/favicon.ico`, `/script.js` and whatnot. The browser will therefore try to fetch these from the webserver, for instance `webserver.local/style.css` and not `webserver.local/router/style.css`. This is the case with my router.

HTTPS connections terminate on your web server, which is up-to-date and supports all the required TLS ciphers. The proxy connects to the old router, (which can even be over HTTP, if necessary: and in that case you can mitigate risk by directly cabling the router and server together).

I haven't specified SSL credentials in the above `VirtualHost`, so the certificate seen by the browser is be that of the web server's own domain. That certificate doesn't match the `router.local` domain; it is a real certificate for external use, like `example.com`. The browser will put up an error, and has to be told to proceed with the `example.com` certificate for `https://router.local`. (Works fine on up-to-date Chrome on a Google phone.)

The way to fix the mismatch is to create a self-signed certificate for the router, and then specify it inside the `VirtualHost` definition using the `SSLCertificateFile` and other parameters; but of course, you then still have a browser-side hoop to go accepting the self-signed certificate which is equally irksome.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i was busy,  "my network" refers to what? I do not have an Apache server or anything similar. I got your solution concept but don't know how to do it specifically (will do so when i know what do you mean by network)

Comment: @OmarShawky I think you have to interpret that in a way that makes sense in your environment.  In my case,  it's network that is connected to this 192.168.1.1 router, and probably controlled by it, in terms of DHCP and DNS and such. In this network I have resources that have 192.168.1.x addresses controlled by this router: PC's, mobile devices, a printer, IPTV streaming box, ... and a web server.

Comment: My web server has a name like `webserver`, pointing to, say, 192.168.1.88.  I told the router to also make the name `router` point to 192.168.1.88.  So then it's possible to try to connect to `https://router.local`, which goes to the webserver. The webserver can be programmed to recognize this `router.local` virtual host, and proxy that to 192.168.1.1.